# How to make vertices more uniform

Tags: modeling, vertices

I used the 'solidify' modifier to make a contact-lens shape. However, it results in this ripply pattern that is visible in the shape's surface. Is there any way to make the vertices more uniform, to match the ones closer to the edge?

[image: mesh with higher vertex density at the polls]
The rippling pattern shows up in the final render. The ripples appeared after applying Blender's 'Solidify' modifier.

Comment: Have you tried the "Even Thickness" and "High Quality Normals" options in the solidify modifier? Those generally produce better more precise results at the expense of slower heavier calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Relax (Loop Tools)

[Loop tools](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/LoopTools) add-on brings in a nice operator called **Relax** that is capable of "relaxing" the selection that should works well in your particular situation.

[image]

In alternative, without adding any external add-on to your Blender's copy, you can select each circumference and run the **To sphere** operator (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and type 1 (max value).

---

You can give a try even to the **Smooth Vertex** operator, but it give best results if the loop to fix is between two loops that have the right shape.

[image]

Comment: Carlo, that's awesome! Dumb question: in the first example, is there an easy way to select the circumference vertices as you did? Right now I'm just clicking on each edge, one at a time.

Comment: You can select edgeloops with Alt+Rmouse, but unfortunately triangles stop edge flow. In this case I selected the nearest edgeloop, expland the selection with ctrl+(+) and then removed the edgeloop from the selection. But there are a few way you can try (e.g. circle select+deselect). It would be another interesting question for the site, if you want ask it out so other can give their tought.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to model an eyeball very fast and using only quads
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just start with a UV sphere then?